# React - Console error with regards to Date format - "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm receiving this error in the console that's related to the "date" type:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Mar 06 2019 18:24:58 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The relevant bit of code that it's referencing:

```
const Conference = types
  .model('Conference', {
    id: types.identifyingNumber,
    date: types.Date,
    description: types.string,
  });

const conferenceStoreBase = types.model({ events: types.array(Event) });
```

And the content is being injected into another component like so:

```
const ConferenceDisplay = inject('conferenceStore')(observer(({ conferenceStore }) => (
<div>
  {
    conferenceStore.conference.map((conference) => {
      const {
        id,
        date,
        description,
      } = conference;

      return (
        <ul key={id}>
          <li>{date}</li>
          <li>{description}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    })
  }
</div>
```

From what I can tell, this has to do with needing to convert the Object into a string element. I'm new to React, so unsure how to proceed from here; any advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to convert a `Date` instance to a string for rendering is to use `date.toLocaleDateString()`.

For example:

```
const today = new Date()
today.toLocaleDateString()
// result: "3/6/2019"
```

You could do this inside of your `ConferenceDisplay` functional component:

```
...
return (
  <ul key={id}>
    <li>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</li>
    <li>{description}</li>
  </ul>
)
...
```

Comment: That was exactly it - thanks! I did a variation on that, and used `.toString()` instead which better suits my purposes. I appreciate your time.